# javascript settimeout reset isn't working

Tags: javascript, settimeout, reset, cleartimeout

I am trying to reset a timer in javascript but is refuses to work, it just starts another function without stopping the previous one.

```
time = ((A[Qused].length)*5000) + 10000
refresh = window.setTimeout(function(){timeup(tc,chosen);}, time);
window.clearTimeout(refresh)
refresh = window.setTimeout(function(){timeup(tc,chosen);}, time);
```

This code is straight from the application and as i explained it doesn't stop the timout, it starts another one though.

Can anyone help please?
thnx in advance

Comment: How can you know the first timer is not reset?

Comment: A [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7BgA/) shows it should work.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the four lines of code you have here so my guess is that this isn't actually what your code looks like.  If you want help, you will have to show us more of the ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us much of your code in the real context, but some of the common reasons for not successfully clearing the previous timer are:

1. Your variable that holds the timer is not a global variable (or in a closure that persists) and thus doesn't survive from one call to the next so when you go to do `clearTimeout(refresh)`, the `refresh` variable doesn't hold the right value.  You can check this by doing a `console.log(refresh)` before you do the `clearTimeout()`.  If this is your problem, then `refresh` will probably be `undefined`.
2. You're accidentally starting more than one timer thus you're overwriting your `refresh` variable and your `clearTimeout(refresh)` only stops that last timer set, not the earlier one.  In some forms of code, it's safest to always do `clearTimeout()` on any prior timer BEFORE you start a new timer to make sure you didn't already have one running or it may make more sense to just check with an `if` statement if you already have one running.

If you want more specific help, you will need to disclose more details of your ACTUAL code because the four lines of code you have above in that exact sequence and all in the same scope do not have the problem you are experiencing - so obviously there's more to the actual code than you've disclosed.

Comment: If it's in the exact order as shown, copied directly from the code (no other code between), neither seems likely. My guess is the OP is mistaken.

Comment: Your answer is useful (but guesswork) but remember to closevote as well ;-)

Comment: Both of those seem likely, thank you ill try to fix that

Comment: @JaredFarrish - there's no way the four lines of code in the question are exactly in order with no intervening code because the last two would just be superfluous.  The OP could just remove those last two lines of code and even if they left them in, there would not be a problem.  I think they're copied from different parts of the program.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I prefer to ask for further clarification before voting to close.  I will vote to close if the OP doesn't engage and clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

example of how to clear settimeout

```
var myVar;

function myFunction()
{
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
}

function myStopFunction()
{
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```